# Is it possible to define a custom basepath for proftpd home directories?

Tags: linux, ftp, ldap, pam, proftpd

I know the `DefaultRoot ~` setting that you can use to jail users into their home directories but I need to customize this.

When authenticating with proftpd I get the user's home-directory from `ldap` via `auth-pam`. I have no control over what the home-directory path will be but I need them to be on my `glusterfs` which is a fusemount I have in `/mnt/glusterfs`.

What I would love to have is that if I get a user's home as `/some/directory` that proftpd would jail them into `/mnt/glusterfs/some/directory`

So basically I'd like to have something like `DefaultRoot /base/path/~`

If you guys (and or gals) can think of any solution be it modifying code or whatever creative solution I'd be glad to hear it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users' normal home directories include the user name, e.g. "/home/foo" for user "foo", then you *might* be able to use something like this:

```
DefaultRoot /mnt/glusterfs/home/%u
```

That `%u` variable will be resolved to the authenticated user name.

Another, more sophisticated approach is to use the [`mod_rewrite`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_rewrite.html) module and the [`RewriteHome`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_auth.html#RewriteHome) directive; the `RewriteHome` directive documentation contains an example of what your regex/substitution might look like.  And the `RewriteHome` functionality applies *regardless* of the source of the home directory, be it LDAP, system functions, *etc*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would work but doesn't cover the use-case where ftp users have shared homedirectories which was something I had to deal with.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I've updated my answer with another approach which might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following directives to create the base path for all the ftp-users. This will restrict users to this path only

```
LDAPGenerateHomedir on
LDAPForceGeneratedHomedir on
LDAPGenerateHomedirPrefix /mnt/glusterfs/some/directory/
```

Comment: I accepted this because it solves the problem. However it requires proftpd to use mod_ldap instead of pam auth.